# This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining'

Tags: polymer, babeljs, rollupjs, lit-element

I am migrating a Polymer project to lit-element and dropping support for older browsers. At the same time I want to start using some newer JS language features, like optional chaining, f.e.

```
let street = contact.address?.street;
```

For development I am using the *es-dev-server*. For building I still use *polymer build* because I need the bare import module specifiers to be replaced by actual file system paths, f.e.

```
import { LitElement } from "lit-element";
```

So far this tool chain worked well but now as I use optional chaining in my code, *polymer build* rejects to build with this error message:

*This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining'*

because of code like the above. I can find no information about which parser that actually is but I thought it might be *Babel* because I found similar error messages in the context of *Babel* on the web.
Therefore I added a .babelrc file with the following content:

```
{  
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
  ]
}
```

and my package.json includes the package as a devDependency:

```
"devDependencies": {
   ...
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.10.4"
   ...   
}
```

Unfortunately this has no effect. The error message persists as if the *Babel* configuration is completely ignored. I also tried a *Babel* key in package.json and also a babel.config.json without success.

Any idea what needs to be done to make this build?

Note: as recommended by the Polymer team itself I would like to switch to the *open-wc* tools. As mentioned above I already use the *es-dev-server* for development but *open-wc* recommends *rollup* for building. But at this time I don't need any bundling, transpiling or optimizations. All I want is the replacement of bare module specifiers such that my code can run with other servers like IIS or nginx.

**Edit:** I have not found a solution to this problem. I want to mention, however, that I switched to *rollup* which worked quite well because rollup does by default build without minifying and keeps the dynamically imported modules in separate files (which of course is the whole purpose of dynamic modules). It correctly replaces bare module specifiers which was my main concern. This allows me to debug my code on other servers (at least most of it, some parts are colored red in Chrome and have only partial debug/symbol information).

Comment: Have you tried building with webpack rather than polymer builds?

Comment: Not yet, I will have a look at it, thanks